# How to regularize $1 - 2 + 0 + 4 - 5 + 0 + 7 - 8 + 0 + \dots $?

Tags: real-analysis, representation-theory, analytic-number-theory

On the internet we could find the [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) L-series https://www.lmfdb.org/L/1/3/3.2/r1/0/0

$$ L(s, \chi_3) = 1 - 2^{-s} +4^{-s}-5^{-s}+7^{-s}-8^{-s}+10^{-s}-11^{-s}+13^{-s}-14^{-s}+16^{-s}-17^{-s}+\dots $$

If I try to set the value to $s=0$ or $s=-1$ we obtain:

- $L(0, \chi_3) = (1 -1 + 0) + (1 - 1 + 0) + (1-1+0)+ \dots$
- $L(-1, \chi_3) = 1 -2 + 0 + 4 - 5 + 0 + 6 - 7 + 0 + \dots $

The web page tells us the value at $s = 1$:

$$ L(1, \chi_3) = 0.6045997880 $$

There is a [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation) listed as:

$$ \Lambda(s) = 3^{s/2}\Gamma(s+1)L(s) = \Lambda(1-s) $$

If we set $s = 0$, we get a plausible looking value for the divergent series just written.

$$ 3^{0/2}\Gamma(0+1)L(0, \chi_3) = 3^{1/2}\Gamma(2)L(1, \chi_3) $$

For reference, the Dirichlet [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(mathematics)) is written as a table:

$$  \begin{array}{c|rr} 
& 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & 1 \\
\chi_2 & 1 & -1
\end{array}$$

Comment: I am a bit lost regarding what exactly you are asking; it it the value of $L(1,\chi_3)$ or $L(-1,\chi_3)$?

Comment: By the way, your functional equation $$L(1-s,\chi_3)=3^{s-1/2}\frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{\Gamma(2-s)}L(s,\chi_3)$$ shows that $$L(-1,\chi_3)=0.$$ Also, using the Fourier series of the Bernoulli polynomial $B_1$, we get $$L(1,\chi_3)=\frac{1}{\sin(2\pi/3)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2n\pi/3)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: What is $\Gamma_{\Bbb R}$ in the lmfdb.org link?